# Matlabs ellipse hours calc

Tags: matlab, geolocation, geocoding, ellipse, hour

I make sundial simulator and i draw ellipse and then i have to draw hours on this ellipse. Every our is specified by:

```
x = a * sin(t);
y = b * cos(t);
```

where:

```
a- length of longer semi-axis
b- length of smaller semi-axis
t- hour in degrees ( 1 hour == 15 degrees)
```

I wrote this function in Matlab:

```
function [hx,hy] = calcHourCoords(ra,rb)
    %input:
    %ra, rb length of semi-axis in ellipse
    %output:
    %hx, hy coords of hour's plot
    hourAngle = 15*180/pi;
    step = 0;
    for i=1:1:24
       hx(i)= ra * sin(step);
       hy(i)= rb * cos(step);
       step = step+hourAngle;
    end
end
```

Finally i get that pic:
[My ellipse and hours points](http://imgur.com/YFZf2Uz)

But is should looks like:
[Correct hour place's](http://imgur.com/2uXaIIV)

Ellipse is correct ( I draw my version for other latitude ).

Maybe someone could help me ?

Sorry for my english :)

**EDIT**

I repair it - just convert degrees to radians.

**EDIT2**

I change source code FYI

Comment: Since you solved your problem, consider putting your own answer in and accepting it, or deleting your question all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function [hx,hy] = calcHourCoords(ra,rb)
    %input:
    %ra, rb length of semi-axis in ellipse 
    %output:
    %hx, hy coords of hour's plot
    hourAngle = 15*pi/180;
    step = 0;
       for i=1:1:24
           hx(i)= ra * sin(step);
           hy(i)= rb * cos(step);
           step = step+hourAngle;
       end
end
```